# Convert a number column into a time format in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm looking for a way to convert a decimal number into a valid `HH:mm:ss` format.

I'm importing data from an SQL database.

One of the columns in my database is labelled `Actual Start Time`.

The values in my database are stored in the following decimal format:

```
73758    // which translates to 07:27:58
114436   // which translates to 11:44:36
```

I cannot simply convert this `Actual Start Time` column into a `Time` format in my Power BI import as it returns errors for some values, saying it doesn't recognise `73758` as a valid 'time'. It needs to have a leading zero for cases such as `73758`.

To combat this, I created a new `Text` column with the following code to append a leading zero:

```
Column = FORMAT([Actual Start Time], "000000")
```

This returns the following results:

```
073758
114436
```

-- which is perfect. Exactly what I needed.

I now want to convert these values into a `Time`.

Simply changing the data type field to `Time` doesn't do anything, returning:

> Cannot convert value '073758' of type Text to type Date.

So I created *another* column with the following code:

```
Column 2 = FORMAT(TIME(LEFT([Column], 2), MID([Column], 3, 2), RIGHT([Column], 2)), "HH:mm:ss")
```

To pass the values `07`, `37` and `58` into a `TIME` format.

This returns the following:

```
 _______________________________________
| Actual Start Date | Column | Column 2 |
|_______________________________________|
|       73758       | 073758 | 07:37:58 |
|       114436      | 114436 | 11:44:36 |
```

Which is what I wanted but is there any other way of doing this? I want to ideally do it in one step without creating additional columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable as suggested by Aldert or you can replace Column by the format function:

```
Time Format = FORMAT(
                    TIME(
                        LEFT(FORMAT([Actual Start Time],"000000"),2),
                        MID(FORMAT([Actual Start Time],"000000"),3,2),
                        RIGHT([Actual Start Time],2)),
                "hh:mm:ss")
```

Edit:

If you want to do this in Power query, you can create a customer column with the following calculation:

```
Time.FromText(
     if Text.Length([Actual Start Time])=5 then Text.PadStart( [Actual Start Time],6,"0") 
     else [Actual Start Time])
```

Once this column is created you can drop the old column, so that you only have one time column in the data. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to do this in the Power Query Editor without creating additional columns? Or do I have to create an additional column anyway?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I, on purpose show you the concept of variables so you can use this in future with more complex queries.

```
TimeC = 
var timeStr = FORMAT([Actual Start Time], "000000")
return FORMAT(TIME(LEFT([timeStr], 2), MID([timeStr], 3, 2), RIGHT([timeStr], 2)), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of this. Will definitely utilise this in the future